# Bash script does not print out cat results until ctrl +c is hit on the keyboard

Tags: linux, bash

Working on script to take the mac addresses from a netdiscover command and print them out to user.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo netdiscover -P > /tmp/discover.txt | sleep 10

for i in $(cat /tmp/discover.txt | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'); do 

echo "testing $i"

done
```

I was expecting bash to present each mac address to me while going through for loop however it only prints out on screen after the script is suspended

Comment: Two notes: (1) [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) (instead, follow [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)); (2) Buffering is a thing.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r i; do echo "testing $i"; done < <(sudo stdbuf -oL netdiscover -P | grep --line-buffered -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')` should behave better, and also completely eliminates the need for a temporary file. Duplicate links with explanations pending.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just found a workaround too. timeout 10 sudo netdiscover -P > /tmp/discover.txt instead of sudo netdiscover -P > /tmp/discover.txt | sleep 10 works too. I think netdiscover was still running causing the script not to end. Not having a tmp file would definitely be better

Comment: _nod_, to explain why that change was needed: you can have stdout of `netdiscover` connected _either_ to `/tmp/discover.txt` _or_ to `sleep 10`, but not to both at once; and if it's going to the file, then obviously it won't get a SIGPIPE when `sleep` exits (or experience an EPIPE when trying to do the next write after that exit), because its output is _not_ connected to `sleep`

Comment: Piping to `sleep` doesn't make any sense anyway, since it  never reads from its stdin. I'm nor clear what you're trying to accomplish there, but whatever it is, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: I don't know `netdiscover`, but according to [this man-page](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/netdiscover), there is no option `-P`. Another thing I would check: Did you verify that _netdiscover_ indeed prints your findings to stdout?